# How to insert a Please Wait form while a query is running

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to display a "Please Wait" form while a 60+ second query is running.  I have the query and the form made (easy enough), except the macro won't bring them together.  Here is my autoexec macro:

1. SetWarnings=False
2. Open Wait Form
3. Run the query & Display Results
4. Close Wait Form

The problem is that I can only see the outline of my wait form while the maketable query is running. I can only guess that the macro doesn't wait for the form to completely load before going to the next step.

#### And just for fun:

The Wait form has a Timer that shows the number of seconds elapsed. How do I run the query while still allowing the form to update itself at the same time?

#### -------Update----------

`Repaint` only updates the background color before moving on to the query. I also tried 6 repaints in a row with no difference (I thought that might get around the bug you people mentioned). The form is very simple.  A single text box that uses "loading" for the control source and a timer function (disabled for the moment). Here is my macro in slightly greater detail:

1. SetWarnings=False
2. Open Wait Form (modal=yes, popup=no)
3. Repaint the form
4. Open a maketable query (this query saves alot of time)
5. Close Wait Form
6. Open the display query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is easy to solve, try putting me.Repaint before the query runs, sometimes access can get a bit lazy with screen painting and you have to force it.

As for the other thing that is a bit more complicated. You would have to execute the query asynchronously. You can do this in ADO by adding the adAsyncExecute option when executing the query. You would then catch the finishing event to tell the users the query is done

Here is a link on the Microsoft knowledge base http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262311

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, Repaint only half-works.  I haven't tried the ADO option yet, sounds hopeful.  See my **Update** for details.

Comment: To my experience the ADO method can (seemingly at random) crash the entire project without warning. At least I have had to replace my ADO solution to a similar problem, because of this. I know use the method described in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you just need to `Repaint` the wait form after it is shown for it to show correctly, it's just a bug in VBA that sometimes causes forms not to be displayed properly even if they are drawn at the correct point in the code.

Secondly, if you set the wait form's `ShowModal` property to false then you will be able to update it through your routine.  I use a public function that takes a 0-100 argument to update a progress bar.  This works best in a loop where you can normally calculate the number of loops remaining and provide an accurate guide to the elapsed progress, but even when performing a series of operations you can time and pass suitable values through to the progress form so that the user is kept informed.  This works better than most Windows progress bars!

[image: xkcd 612]

Comment: The problem with the progress bar updating is that if the OP is just running a standard query there is no way to measure its progress as the code execution will just pause on the execute line until finished. The only way would be to execute the query asynchronously and watch for the finish event. Whilst you are waiting you can of course update some kind of progress indicator using whatever method suits

Comment: heh. I remember that xkcd strip :)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, Repaint only half-works and showmodal=No only makes things worse (the Wait form stays in the background).  See my **Update** for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Action Query you can track the number of executed rows by using a vba-function which returns the same value that was passed to it. Of course you have to know the total number of rows, to know when the query is done or display progress (This can often be achieved relatively fast using a lightweight counting query*).

```
'first some global vars to keep track of the number
Dim lngCurrentRow as Long
Dim lngTotalRows as Long 'We assume lngTotalRows have been set elsewhere

'Here is the function
Public Function UpdateProgress(FieldValue as Variant) as Variant

    lngCurrentRow = Nz(lngCurrentRow, 0)

    If (lngCurrentRow >= lngTotalRows) then
        MsgBox "Query Done!"
    Else
        'Do stuff to show progress
    End If

    lngCurrentRow = lngCurrentRow + 1

End Function
```

For displaying the progress I have used an Unbound form, with an empty textfield with transparent background (progressFrame) and a label (progressLabel) which has a blue background and is placed behind the textbox to the left. For each call to UpdateProgress you can then set the width of the label:

```
progressLabel.Width = progressFrame.Width * (lngCurrentRow / lngTotalRows)
```

*: F.ex. if the query is based on one table, with some added data, so that the number of records the query will produce is equal to that of the table, a count can be done on the table alone so that it will be faster..

I hope this was helpful, or at least inspiring :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a pop up form which took a few seconds before it displayed the text which informs the user that something is processing so please wait. I added the line of code below after the code which opens the form and before the next bit of code which runs the update queries (which takes a while hence the need to inform the user that something was processing)

DoCmd.RepaintObject acForm, "frmMyForm"

Works perfectly for me.